# Adapter for an object that implenets ITreeNode interface to TreeNode for TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview

suppose We have the interface :

```
public interface ITreeNode
    {
        string Text { get; set; }
        IEnumerable<ITreeNode> Nodes { get; set; }
    }
```

Suppose that we have the first node of a tree where every object implents that interface.

What is an easy way to display that tree ( a tree of ITreeNode ) in TreeView?

In other word, how do I adapt the entire tree of ITreeNode to System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode for System.Windows.Forms.TreeView ?

Please note : The above interface is just for getting an idea, if an alternative way for adpating trees nodes of some type to TreeNodes for TreeView exist please advise.

Comment: Pretty unclear.  You could add a *new* node to the treeview whose Text property you set to ITreeNode.Text.

Comment: #Hans : That does not convert the rest of the tree, Only the top node. I think you are right it is unclear, I'll modify it. Modified!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Forms `TreeView` will only ever operate on the type `TreeNode`, so you will need some kind of conversion if you want to use instances of `ITreeNode` with the control. I suggest an extension method, such as the one below:

```
public static class TreeViewExtensions {

    public static void Add(this TreeNodeCollection nodes, ITreeNode node) {
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(node.Text);
        foreach (ITreeNode child in node.Nodes) treeNode.Nodes.Add(child);
        nodes.Add(treeNode);
    }
}
```

Then you can just add your node (and all children, and all children's children, etc) to a `TreeView` control with little fuss:

```
myTreeView.Nodes.Add(myInstanceOfITreeNode);
```

With that said, there isn't a huge advantage in working with objects of a foreign interface and *then* converting to a `TreeNode` representation - you might as well just work directly with the actual node class.

Comment: Thank you, but my problem was that objects of the foreign interface is all i had, there was too much properties in the other object that I decided to hide it by using the interface instead. But I am totally open to the idea "you might as well just work directly with the actual node class." only if I knew what you mean.

Comment: @Arjang By that, I mean changing your representation from `ITreeNode` to `TreeNode` - however this may not be convenient. You could also look at extending the TreeNode class - it's not sealed, so you could write a derived class that has all the additional properties you require.

Comment: @Bradly : This is still a good answer, just now needed to use it again. Thanks again.